# Beginner issue with knockout-kendo.js

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I've used kendo UI quite a bit and have been using knockout.js recently.  I'm trying to use the library knockout-kendo.js to render kendo inputs using knockout bindings.  I'm trying to make a simple numeric input formatted for currency and with the spinners disabled.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious but here is my simple binding:

```
<input type="text" 
       data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { spinners: false, format: 'c0' }" />
```

It is successfully rendering a kendo numeric text box but with the default kendo options, not currency, spinners enabled, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default option for that binding is `value`. When it doesn't find a `value`property on the options, then it assumes that you are binding directly against `value`. This means that you options are getting passed through.

The easiest fix is to either bind against some value like:

```
<input type="text" 
   data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: myValue, spinners: false, format: 'c0' }" />
```

or if you really don't want to bind a value, then you can do:

```
<input type="text" 
   data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: null, spinners: false, format: 'c0' }" />
```

Comment: Ah ha!  Thank you so much.  I knew there had to be one very simple thing I was overlooking.  Adding that value option solved my issue.